# STM32F4 OTG_FS Leakage

Tags: cpu

We have designed a system using [STM32F405](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/DM00037051.pdf) CPU.

There is a problem when I give a Vbus (5V) I can see a leakage of 50mA prior from turning on the CPU meaning I did not give any supply to the CPU( 3V3_D and 3V3_A, 2V0).
I isolate the CPU circuit and confirmed that  the current is going to the CPU side so the leakage is going to the OTG_FS (PA9). I also removed the CPU and the leakage was gone.

Is this normal? How can I eliminate this leakage which is quite high for CPU.
Is there a possible problem with our design?

Appreciate if you can give an immediate response to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet isn't entirely clear on how VUSB is handled, but presumably, it's a 5-V tolerant pin. However, it does state under "Absolute Maximum Ratings" that the voltage on any 5V-tolerant pin can't exceed V<sub>DD</sub> + 4 volts. If you don't have power applied to the chip (V<sub>DD</sub> = 0V), then applying a VUSB of 5V exceeds this limit.

If this is meant to be a bus-powered device, you need to make sure the CPU gets power right away from VUSB.

If not, then you need to arrange the power to the CPU so that it can be powered up by VUSB and then put into a low-power state whenever the external supply is not present.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What will be the effect on the CPU during this scenario? Will it decrease the life span of the CPU? IF there will be no effect I can tolerate this situation.

Comment: "Absolute Maximum Ratings" must **never** be exceeded. The chip may or may not survive, but no guarantees can be made about its future performance.